# Meaning of "on a rolling basis"

Tags: word-meaning

The words "on a rolling basis", as it seems to me, might have different meanings depending on the context in which they are used (but I am not sure, as the meaning of these words is beyond my grasp).

Here is the context:

> "Under s. 44 of the Terrorism Act 2000, a senior police officer could grant a stop and search authorisation for a designated area where he considered it ‘expedient’ to do so for the prevention of acts of terrorism. This was subject to confirmation by the Secretary of State. Once the authorisation had been granted, s. 45 of the Act empowered the police to stop any person or vehicle in that area and search them for articles of a kind which could be used ‘in connection with terrorism... The authorisation did not even have to be considered necessary for preventing acts of terrorism in order to be granted. Authorisations had been made for London on ***a rolling basis*** ever since the power of authorisation was first granted."

My understanding is that, in this context, the words mean "almost regularly, as the need arises".

There is another context:

> There are two trustees up for appointment in each year for three years terms ***on a rolling basis***.

In this context, they mean, in my view, "two trustee are appointed for a term of three years who can be reappointed for a further three years' period and further so on".

Third example:

> All relevant market information should be published on ***a rolling basis*** in a timely manner.

Would you please share your views on the meaning of "a rolling basis" in these contexts?

Answer (score 1):

"On a rolling basis" could be used to refer to tasks that are "ad hoc", or "when required", but with the inference that this is part of an *ongoing arrangement*.

For example, a "rolling monthly contract" can mean a *continuous*, unbroken contract, but one that is effectively renewed each month. So it could go on for years, but could cease at the end of any given month.

I think what your text is trying to say is that the police have not been granted permanent 'blanket' authority to stop and search, but the authorisation to do so is granted whenever required, so the resulting effect is that of a rolling, or continuous arrangement.

Comment: I do apologise, I have edited to add two examples to my original question. But otherwise, many thanks for your response.